# PyOpenGL, Pygame, and shaders don't seem to cooperate

Tags: python, glsl, pygame, pyopengl

I've been working through this [excellent tutorial](http://duriansoftware.com/joe/An-intro-to-modern-OpenGL.-Table-of-Contents.html) on modern OpenGL programming, and I'm slowly adapting it to work on PyOpenGL and pygame. However, I'm having the hardest time getting what should be a "trivial" example to work with perspective geometry. Code is as found here:

```
import pygame
import numpy as np
from OpenGL.GL import *

##########################################
# Define the simple pass-through shaders
##########################################
import cStringIO
vshade = cStringIO.StringIO("""
#version 110

uniform mat4 p_matrix;
uniform mat4 mv_matrix;

attribute vec4 position;

void main()
{
    vec4 eye_position = mv_matrix * position;
    gl_Position = p_matrix * eye_position;
}
""")

fshade = cStringIO.StringIO("""
#version 110

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
}
""")

###################################################
# Set up a simple square composed of two triangles
###################################################
verts = np.array([[0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,1],[1,1,0,1],[0,1,0,1]]).astype(np.float32)
polys = np.array([[0,1,3],[1,2,3]]).astype(np.ushort)
mv_matrix = np.eye(4)
mv_matrix[:3,-1] = [0,0,2]
projection = np.array([ [ 1.071429,  0.      ,  0.      ,  0.      ],
                       [ 0.      ,  1.428571,  0.      ,  0.      ],
                       [ 0.      ,  0.      ,  1.000489, -0.125031],
                       [ 0.      ,  0.      ,  1.      ,  0.      ]])

def _make_shader(stype, src):
    shader = glCreateShader(stype)
    glShaderSource(shader, src)
    glCompileShader(shader)

    if not glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS):
        err = glGetShaderInfoLog(shader)
        glDeleteShader(shader)
        raise Exception(err)
    return shader

##################################
# Initialize pygame and opengl
##################################
flags = pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.OPENGL
pygame.display.set_mode((800,600), flags)

glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
glClearColor(0.5,0.5,0.5,1)
glClearDepth(1.0)
glDepthFunc(GL_LESS)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)


######################################
# Make the shaders and programs 
######################################
vshade = _make_shader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vshade.read())
fshade = _make_shader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fshade.read())

program = glCreateProgram()
glAttachShader(program, vshade)
glAttachShader(program, fshade)
glLinkProgram(program)

#######################################
# Fetch positions, push poly to card
#######################################
posidx = glGetAttribLocation(program, "position")
pidx = glGetUniformLocation(program, "p_matrix")
mvidx = glGetUniformLocation(program, "mv_matrix")

vbuf = glGenBuffers(1)
ebuf = glGenBuffers(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuf)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
    verts.astype(np.float32).ravel(), GL_STATIC_DRAW)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebuf)
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
    polys.astype(np.uint16).ravel(), GL_STATIC_DRAW)

#####################################
# Enter main drawing loop!
#####################################
glViewport(0,0,800,600)
while True:
    # Clear the screen
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glUseProgram(program)

    # Push the transforms to the card
    glUniformMatrix4fv(pidx, 1, GL_TRUE, projection.astype(np.float32))
    glUniformMatrix4fv(mvidx, 1, GL_TRUE, mv_matrix.astype(np.float32))

    # Enable the position attribute
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posidx)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuf)
    glVertexAttribPointer( posidx, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 4*4, 0)

    # Draw the two triangles
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebuf);
    glDrawElements(
        GL_TRIANGLES,           # mode
        len(polys)*3,           # count
        GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT,      # type
        0                       # element array buffer offset
    )
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(posidx)

    #inspect the values -- does it make sense?
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbuf)
    l, l2 = (GLfloat*16)() , (GLushort*6)()
    glGetBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 4*4*4, l)
    print list(l)
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebuf)
    glGetBufferSubData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 2*6, l2)
    print list(l2)
    glGetUniformfv(program, pidx, l)
    print list(l)
    glGetUniformfv(program, mvidx, l)
    print list(l)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Based on my understanding, I should get a red square to cover the upper right quadrant of the screen, but nothing I'm doing seems to affect the fully gray screen. Any insight into what's wrong would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please add your code, otherwise we can't help

Comment: There's a pastebin link right there with the full code. I even tried a direct pass-through version with no projection in the shader, and still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

After condensing the problem down even further and making a nearly line-by-line match in C, I realized that it was a problem in pyopengl exclusively, not in pygame. I posted on their mailing list with the example code, and found the answer:

http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=28875534

It seems that there's a slight "misfeature" in how they implemented the ctypes wrapper for glDrawElements. The final argument, which gives the offset, requires type (void*). The value passed in by a simple 0 doesn't work, and needs to be wrapped with GLvoidp(0).